# Reloading particular html slide after pressing submit button

Tags: php, html

I am using six sliders in html page and each slider have more than one submit button.Suppose if i am using slide number two and i did some operation on it like pressing submit button and sending request to server.

Problem:

How can i go back to same slide number after clicking submit button because
when i press submit button it reload the first slide.

Attempted Code:

SCRIPT

```
<p id="slidetry"></p>
<script>

function Attempt() {
    location.hash = "Slide1";
    var a = "You are now in " + location.hash;
    document.getElementById("slidetry").innerHTML = a;
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<form  name="form" method="post"  action="index.php">
<input type="submit" value="ON" name="on" style="height:40px; width:100px" onClick="Attempt()">
</form>
```

PHP code taken from www.raspberry-pi-geek.com

```
<?php
         $setmode17 = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g mode 17 out");
         if(isset($_POST['on'])){
                 $gpio_on = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 17 1");

         }
         else if(isset($_POST['off'])){
                 $gpio_off = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 17 0");

         }
 ?>
```

Comment: You would have to prevent the default behavior of the submit button and use a method to submit the form without reloading the page(using AJAX for example).

Comment: Thanks for the response APAD1 can you please help with some hint codes..